# Fix IP for Docker

Tags: c#, docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I have several Microservices  that each have a separate Docker container. It is in CS 2017, **Docker Desktop for Windows**. These services are talking each other using IP address that Docker  assigned. The problem is that in Debug mode the project in Visual studio every time I  change something and build the project the IP of docker is changing so I have to go through the code and  change the IP, is there anyway to have a fix the IP or use static IP?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a network for your project

```
docker network create myproject
```

Then when you run you docker containers give each of them a name

```
docker run --name service1 --net myproject service1image
```

Now other services also using same method. Now each service can reach other using the the name

Comment: actually I tried this before and I am getting this error: Error response from daemon: plugin not found

Comment: I tried this before posting. Docker for Windows v17.06.0-ce and Hyper-V VM